# Why does my phone vibrate indefinitely?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use a vibration pattern when vibrating the phone. I'm using:

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
                long[] longs = { 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0 , 0, 0, 2 };
                v.vibrate(longs, 1);
```

and it just doesn't stop vibrating.

1. If I use `v.vibrate(longs, -1);` it doesn't vibrate at all.
2. If I use `v.vibrate(longs, 0);` it doesn't vibrate at all.
3. If I use `v.vibrate(longs, 2);` or any number higher than 1, it vibrates indefinitely.
4. If I change the long values to so they're higher or lower it makes no difference.

I've read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#vibrate(long[],%20int)) and some [t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950338/how-to-make-an-android-device-vibrate)[u](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242260/how-can-i-make-my-device-vibrate)[t](http://android.konreu.com/developer-how-to/vibration-examples-for-android-phone-development/)[o](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/11/vibrate-android-device-with-example.html)[rials](http://www.openandroid.in/vibrate-android-device-with-example.html) and I don't think I've done anything wrong here. Why isn't it vibrating properly?

Note: I use other apps that vibrate in patterns properly so I know it's not an issue with my phone.

Comment: I'm adding my own answer as I have found a solution. I don't understant it though, so if somebody could add an explanation of _why_ this code I'm about to add works as expected then that'd be great.

Comment: I don't see the relation between the comment `// Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
` and the code.

Comment: @njzk2 That's irrelavent. I just haven't removed the comment after changing the code a little.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read the documentation for [vibrate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#vibrate(long[],%20int)).

With `2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0 , 0, 0, 2`, you are saying: "wait for 2 ms, vibrate for 0 ms, wait for 0 ms, vibrate for 0 ms, wait for 2 ms, vibrate for 0 ms, wait for 0 ms, vibrate for 0 ms, wait for 2 ms". Obviously, this pattern never vibrates, unless you repeat the pattern (which has an odd number of intervals).

When you pass anything other than -1 as the second argument, the pattern is repeated using the second argument as the index into the pattern at which to start repeating. Since you never seem to call `v.cancel()`, this repetition never ends, causing endless vibration (because at some point in the repetition, you will have non-0 vibration interval).

Comment: Thank you @cybersam, I did originally read the documentation. Don't know how I managed to miss the part where they talk about the on-off's.

Answer (score 2):

> Why isn't it vibrating properly?

Well...

First, zero milliseconds is a really short time. Users will not notice a vibration that is happening for zero milliseconds, and users will not notice a gap between vibrations that is happening for zero milliseconds.

Second, two milliseconds is a really short time. Your entire pattern takes six milliseconds for each pass (with a repeat value of `0`), or four milliseconds for the second and subsequent passes (with a repeat value of `1`, since that skips the first element of your pattern, which is one of your three two-millisecond values). There are hundreds of these patterns per second, which is not going to be discernable by the user.

I suggest that you get rid of the zeros, and use reasonable numbers of milliseconds for the rest. This is on top of cybersam's suggestions of eventually calling `cancel()` and thinking through whether you want an even or odd number of elements in your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The code from the second answer on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950338/how-to-make-an-android-device-vibrate?lq=1) is working for me. It vibrates in a pattern and then stops once the pattern is finished:

```
// Get instance of Vibrator from current Context
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

// Start without a delay
// Vibrate for 100 milliseconds
// Sleep for 1000 milliseconds
long[] pattern = {0, 100, 1000};

// The '0' here means to repeat indefinitely
// '0' is actually the index at which the pattern keeps repeating from (the start)
// To repeat the pattern from any other point, you could increase the index, e.g. '1'
v.vibrate(pattern, 0);
```